# Checklist to configure programs to (not) run at startup in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, boot, powershell, autostart

I'm asking specifically for Asus Splendid, I'd like to run it whenever I want so that it does not start every time I start windows. I know it's a program that is started because the screen looks different after a few seconds of booting up.

However this is a general question that could be useful for many people with similar problems with other programs.

Some applications have the option to be configured to run when windows starts (well done, developers, big thanks) but some applications do not (so much for freedom, customization and usability).

So far I've checked the registry `windows key + r` then type `regedit` then check:

- `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]`
- `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]`

There is also a [fancier way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/monad/archive/2006/03/08/546548.aspx) to explore the registry using powershell, but I found no difference in the results.

I have also checked the services, `windows key + r` then `services.msc`, there you can set the services to manual start, but it does not seem to be there either.

Therefore, I've no idea about why is this program starting. There have to be more configuration settings for the start up, or I may have been misled by a name that isn't clear.

For these reasons I think that **a list with all possible places to check** (aka: checklist) would be definitively very good and useful for many people and I was not able to find it so far.

I don't want to install anything like "regcleaner" for several reasons but mostly it boils down to the fact that I don't like installing things.

I don't want to uninstall Asus Splendid because it happens to be good, sometimes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Location list

This is the merged list of all 32-bit and 64-bit locations used by [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) (as of version 12.03) running on Windows XP and later:

### Registry

```
HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Scrnsave.exe
HKCU\Software\Classes\*\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
HKCU\Software\Classes\*\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers
HKCU\Software\Classes\.cmd
HKCU\Software\Classes\.exe
HKCU\Software\Classes\AllFileSystemObjects\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
HKCU\Software\Classes\AllFileSystemObjects\ShellEx\DragDropHandlers
HKCU\Software\Classes\AllFileSystemObjects\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers
HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{083863F1-70DE-11d0-BD40-00A0C911CE86}\Instance
HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{7ED96837-96F0-4812-B211-F13C24117ED3}\Instance
HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{ABE3B9A4-257D-4B97-BD1A-294AF496222E}\Instance
HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{AC757296-3522-4E11-9862-C17BE5A1767E}\Instance
HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\Shellex\CopyHookHandlers
HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\Shellex\DragDropHandlers
HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\Shellex\PropertySheetHandlers
HKCU\Software\Classes\Drive\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
HKCU\Software\Classes\Exefile\Shell\Open\Command\(Default)
HKCU\Software\Classes\Filter
HKCU\Software\Classes\Folder\Shellex\ColumnHandlers
HKCU\Software\Classes\Folder\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
HKCU\Software\Classes\Folder\ShellEx\DragDropHandlers
HKCU\Software\Classes\Folder\ShellEx\ExtShellFolderViews
HKCU\Software\Classes\Folder\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers
HKCU\Software\Classes\Htmlfile\Shell\Open\Command\(Default)
HKCU\Software\Classes\Protocols\Filter
HKCU\Software\Classes\Protocols\Handler
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Ctf\LangBarAddin
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\Components
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Explorer Bars
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Extensions
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\UrlSearchHooks
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Drivers32
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\Install\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\Install\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Runonce
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Load
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Run
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellServiceObjects
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\Shell
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ShellServiceObjectDelayLoad
HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop\Scrnsave.exe
HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\Scripts\Logoff
HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\Scripts\Logon
HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{083863F1-70DE-11d0-BD40-00A0C911CE86}\Instance
HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{7ED96837-96F0-4812-B211-F13C24117ED3}\Instance
HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{ABE3B9A4-257D-4B97-BD1A-294AF496222E}\Instance
HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{AC757296-3522-4E11-9862-C17BE5A1767E}\Instance
HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Explorer Bars
HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Extensions
HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Drivers32
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\.cmd
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\.exe
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\AllFileSystemObjects\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\AllFileSystemObjects\ShellEx\DragDropHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\AllFileSystemObjects\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{083863F1-70DE-11d0-BD40-00A0C911CE86}\Instance
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{7ED96837-96F0-4812-B211-F13C24117ED3}\Instance
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{ABE3B9A4-257D-4B97-BD1A-294AF496222E}\Instance
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{AC757296-3522-4E11-9862-C17BE5A1767E}\Instance
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Shellex\CopyHookHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Shellex\DragDropHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Shellex\PropertySheetHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Drive\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Exefile\Shell\Open\Command\(Default)
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Filter
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\Shellex\ColumnHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\ShellEx\DragDropHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\ShellEx\ExtShellFolderViews
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Htmlfile\Shell\Open\Command\(Default)
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Protocols\Filter
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Protocols\Handler
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Ctf\LangBarAddin
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Explorer Bars
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Extensions
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AutoStartOnConnect
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AutoStartOnDisconnect
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Drivers32
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\Install\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\Install\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Runonce
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\Install\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunonceEx
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Appinit_Dlls
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\IconServiceLib
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\AppSetup
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\GinaDLL
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\LsaStart
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Notify
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SaveDumpStart
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\ServiceControllerStart
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\System
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Taskman
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\UIHost
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Userinit
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\VmApplet
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Provider Filters
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\PLAP Providers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\SharedTaskScheduler
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellExecuteHooks
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellServiceObjects
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts\Shutdown
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts\Startup
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\Shell
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Approved
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ShellServiceObjectDelayLoad
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\Scripts\Logoff
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\Scripts\Logon
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\Scripts\Shutdown
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\Scripts\Startup
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\*\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\*\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\AllFileSystemObjects\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\AllFileSystemObjects\ShellEx\DragDropHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\AllFileSystemObjects\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{083863F1-70DE-11d0-BD40-00A0C911CE86}\Instance
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{7ED96837-96F0-4812-B211-F13C24117ED3}\Instance
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{ABE3B9A4-257D-4B97-BD1A-294AF496222E}\Instance
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{AC757296-3522-4E11-9862-C17BE5A1767E}\Instance
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\Directory\Background\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\Directory\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\Directory\Shellex\CopyHookHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\Directory\Shellex\DragDropHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\Directory\Shellex\PropertySheetHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\Drive\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\Folder\Shellex\ColumnHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\Folder\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\Folder\ShellEx\DragDropHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\Folder\ShellEx\ExtShellFolderViews
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\Folder\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Explorer Bars
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Extensions
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AutoStartOnConnect
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AutoStartOnDisconnect
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Drivers32
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Appinit_Dlls
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\SharedTaskScheduler
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellExecuteHooks
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellServiceObjects
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ShellServiceObjectDelayLoad
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\BootVerificationProgram\ImagePath
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Authentication Packages
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Notification Packages
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\OSConfig\Security Packages
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Security Packages
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\AlternateShell
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SecurityProviders
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ServiceControlManagerExtension
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\AppCertDlls
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\BootExecute
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Execute
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\KnownDlls
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\S0InitialCommand
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\SetupExecute
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\Wds\rdpwd\StartupPrograms
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\InitialProgram
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinSock2\Parameters\NameSpace_Catalog5\Catalog_Entries
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinSock2\Parameters\NameSpace_Catalog5\Catalog_Entries64
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinSock2\Parameters\Protocol_Catalog9\Catalog_Entries
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinSock2\Parameters\Protocol_Catalog9\Catalog_Entries64
HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\CmdLine
```

### Folders

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
C:\Documents and Settings\<userName>\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar\Settings.ini
C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
C:\Windows\System32\Tasks
C:\Windows\Tasks
```

Comment: I would like to do exactly that, but manually. I'll check the RunOnce registry key next, thank you :)

Comment: @Trylks I've edited my answer adding all locations used by Autoruns.

Comment: perfect, that's exactly what I wanted :) thank you very much

Comment: Nice list, where do you get it? I hope not reversing Autoruns app :) I cannot find this list for the newest version of Autoruns.

Comment: @Dolmayan I've just updated it, no reversing required. In fact, you could create one yourself: start Autoruns, change the filter options so that the only checked setting is **Include empty locations**, and rescan. When the program is ready, save the results as `.txt`. You then have to parse the file and remove the clutter (i.e. any entries available), leaving just the actual locations. At this point you can sort the new list, and remove duplicates (if any).